# Remap entity to a child class implementation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design

Here is the simplified model I am working with:

```
public class Info
{
   [Key]
   public int Id {get; set;}

   [Required]
   public DateTime PublishedAt {get; set;}
}

public class Review: Info
{
   [Required]
   public DateTime ReviwedAt {get; set;}
}
```

At a particular stage I have an instance of the `Info` object that I would like to "upgrade" to `Review` stage (all required information for the update will be supplied)

Here is the point of my hesitation... Maybe I am thinking too much in SQL Server terms...

As soon as both `Info` and `Review` entities will be stored in the same table, is there is a statdard way in EF to "upgrade" an existed `Info` record to `Review` Discriminator with assigning a value to [ReviwedAt] ?

If no, if there is a pattern/best practic that would soulve similar issue (switch object stages and keep the change history traceble )?

Comment: Short answer - no. And not only "standard" - there is no any way to change the stored entity type using EF.

Comment: @IvanStoev: If no, if there is a pattern/best practic that would soulve similar issue (switch object stages and keep the change history traceble )?